# H2/PostgreSQL/Hibernate: Using shared locks causes org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, locking, h2

in productive I'm running PostgreSQL 9.6 and Hibernate 5.4.16. The following code works just fine:

```
  final CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
  final CriteriaQuery<JpaClass> query = cb.createQuery(JpaClass.class);
  final Root<JpaClass> fromClass = query.from(JpaClass.class);
  final Join<JpaClass, JpaObject> classObjects = fromClass.join(JpaClass_.object);
  query.select(fromClass).where(cb.equal(classObjects.get(JpaObject_.objectId), objectId));
  final TypedQuery<JpaClass> tq = getEntityManager().createQuery(query);
  final EntityGraph<JpaClass> graph = createClassEntityGraph();
  tq.setHint(JpaRepository.JAVAX_PERSISTENCE_LOADGRAPH, graph);
  tq.setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ);
  return tq.getSingleResult();
```

In my unit-test I'm using H2 1.4.200 however and it comes to this exception:

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax Error in SQL Command

The SQL sent is:

```
SELECT
  # lots of attributes nothing spectacular...
FROM
  CLASS JPACLASS0_
  INNER JOIN OBJECT JPAOBJECT1_ ON JPACLASS0_.OBJECT_ID = JPAOBJECT_.ID
WHERE
  JPAOBJECT1_.OBJECTID = 2 FOR SHARE [*] OF JPACLASS0_,
  JPAOBJECT1_;
```

This is the connection information I am using for H2:

```
   private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:h2:mem:history;MODE=PostgreSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=FALSE";
```

Things I have already found out:

- When removing the LockMode in the Hibernate-Query-Builder, the test
  runs fine
- H2 connection options MVCC, MV_STORE,
  SELECT_FOR_UPDATE_MVCC do not solve the problem unless   I have
  chosen the wrong combination out of those...
- The problem is not existent for Hibernate 5.1 (but I can't go back from 5.4)

Anyone can help me pleeeaase?

Comment: H2 1.4.200 throws exception on attempt to use `MVCC` or `SELECT_FOR_UPDATE_MVCC` setting, so your connection URL is not actually used. These settings work only in 1.4.197 and older versions. Anyway, you can't use PostgreSQL dialects of Hibernate with H2, these dialects use some PostgreSQL-only features, such as `FOR SHARE OF` in your query. You have some problem in your testing configuration, you need to show it here.

Comment: This is another good example why testing on a different database system then the one used in production doesn't really test anything.